# Pyinstaller Error when try to create exe file

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

When i try to create the executable for my program using `pyinstaller --onefile gui.py` it gives me this error. pyqt5 and all the required packages are installed for the program but when i tried to create the executable it gives me this error what is wrong with the process

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\oshada.i\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import util as _util
  File "C:\Users\oshada.i\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\__init__.py", line 103, in <module>
    from .concurrency import asyncio
  File "C:\Users\oshada.i\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\concurrency.py", line 20, in <module>
    from ._concurrency_py3k import await_only
  File "C:\Users\oshada.i\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_concurrency_py3k.py", line 8, in <module>
    import asyncio
  File "C:\Users\oshada.i\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\asyncio\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .base_events import *
  File "C:\Users\oshada.i\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\asyncio\base_events.py", line 296
    future = tasks.async(future, loop=self)
                   ^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\oshada.i\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\oshada.i\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\oshada.i\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\oshada.i\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 178, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\oshada.i\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 59, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\oshada.i\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 845, in main
    build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
  File "C:\Users\oshada.i\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 767, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "E:\Imalka\VarCheck\gui.spec", line 7, in <module>
    a = Analysis(
  File "C:\Users\oshada.i\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 319, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Users\oshada.i\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 173, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Users\oshada.i\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 487, in assemble
    self.graph.process_post_graph_hooks(self)
  File "C:\Users\oshada.i\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 326, in process_post_graph_hooks
    module_hook.post_graph(analysis)
  File "C:\Users\oshada.i\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 398, in post_graph
    self._load_hook_module()
  File "C:\Users\oshada.i\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 361, in _load_hook_module
    self._hook_module = importlib_load_source(self.hook_module_name, self.hook_filename)
  File "C:\Users\oshada.i\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 620, in importlib_load_source
    return mod_loader.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 548, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1063, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 888, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 290, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 719, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\oshada.i\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-sqlalchemy.py", line 31, in <module>
    dialects = eval(dialects.strip())
  File "<string>", line 0
    
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You should post the code , there is a syntax error

Comment: here is the [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/uwtkth/pyinstaller_error/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) to code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found a solution to fix the error. it because of the asyncio package remove the package using `pip uninstall asyncio` and run the pyinstaller it will compile the .exe file